# How to check if JSON object exists

Tags: php, adobe-analytics

I made a post regarding a code for Adobe Analytics API. I am using a code to retrieve the first and second element (dimension) which is called 'breakdown'. The number varies depending on the data we have for this element.

I am using a loop with i=10 but I want to take everything. Which is the best way to achieve that?

I am using this code:

```
foreach ($json->report->data as $element) 
{
        // putting an excessive number for i
        for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
        {
            // checking if the object exists
            if (isset($element->breakdown[0]->breakdown[$i]->name)) 
            {
                echo $element->breakdown[0]->breakdown[$i]->name;

                // putting the data in a list I created before
                array_push($list, array(''.$element->year.'-'.$element->month.'-'.$element->day, $element->breakdown[0]->name, $element->breakdown[0]->breakdown[$i]->name, $element->breakdown[0]->breakdown[$i]->counts[0], $element->breakdown[0]->breakdown[$i]->counts[1]));
            }
            else
            {
                // Break the loop. All the objects are in the row. So, if there is not any for i=45 then there won't be any for i>45
                continue;
            }

        }
}
```

where I am trying to get all the objects. I am checking if the objects exist. If they don't, I want this loop to stop (second loop).

Comment: Any particular reason why you aren't just using a `foreach` loop for the inner one too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the loop with break.
for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

```
foreach ($json->report->data as $element) 
{
    // putting an excessive number for i
    for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
    {
        // checking if the object exists
        if (isset($element->breakdown[0]->breakdown[$i]->name)) 
        {
            echo $element->breakdown[0]->breakdown[$i]->name;

            // putting the data in a list I created before
            array_push($list, array(''.$element->year.'-'.$element->month.'-'.$element->day, $element->breakdown[0]->name, $element->breakdown[0]->breakdown[$i]->name, $element->breakdown[0]->breakdown[$i]->counts[0], $element->breakdown[0]->breakdown[$i]->counts[1]));
        }
        else
        {
            // Break the loop. 
            break;
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: What is the difference between break and continue exactly? I thought that continue would stop the for loop and continue with the foreach. I also thought that break would just stop looping for the specific i. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is in the name. Break "Breaks" the loops. While Continue goes to the next iteration. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364757/difference-between-break-and-continue-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Use `break` instead of `continue` to exit a loop

`break` stops the current loop `continue` goes to the next iteration of the loop.

To get out of both loops use `break 2;`

Comment: Great. Thank you for the info on break 2 !