# PHP Foreach loop not stopping

Tags: php, loops, foreach

i have a strange behaviour with my script, the foreach loop only stops if i echo results, so it just continues to insert values... Only stops if i use echo to show some iterations... Below is important part of code:

```
$looparray=array
(
"1"=>array(
        "something1", 
        "something2",
        "something3",
                ),
"2"=>array(
                ),
"3"=>array(
                ),
"4"=>array(
                ),
"5"=>array(
                ),
"6"=>array(
                )
);
foreach ($looparray as $key => $value) {

    if(count($value)=='0') // skip empty arrays
    {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($value as $singlevalue) {
        for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
        {
            echo $i . '<br />';  //if i don't use it, neverending loop ?!
        }
    }
}
```

So if i'm not echo-ing then loop is not stopping at 5... Of course i have a lot of stop in the inner for loop, but those are not important... So why is it happening?

Comment: Your for loop is correct. I ran your code without the echo statement and it completed normally without an infinite loop. There must be something else going on in the rest of your code.

Comment: _Of course i have a lot of stop in the inner for loop, but those are not important_ They might be. If this is not your complete code, it's going to be hard to help you...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop your looping just use `unset($singlevalue);` after the foreach loop.

Comment: Or use `break`;

Answer (score -1):

Use [break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364757/difference-between-break-and-continue-in-php) to leave the loop.

**Reading Material**

[`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Comment: Hmm , im not a php noobie....  
"break" is only good if i WANT TO leave the loop when a condition is met, however i don't want to leave the loop, i want it to go till it ends... But it does not end, that is my problem...