# PHP in_array not working properly?

Tags: php, associative-array

I'm working on in_array() method. If the value read is already in the array it should be skipped and proceed to the next value. If the current value is not on the array yet, it should be pushed to the array.

**here's my code:**

```
while ($Result_Data_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($Result)){ //130 rows from database
      $Res_Array = array();
      $SQL_Result_Time = $Result_Data_2['Interpretation_Time'];

      /* Some statements here */

      if(in_array($SQL_Result_Time, $Res_Array, true)){
          break;
      }
      else{
          array_push($Res_Array, $Number, $SQL_Questionnaire_ID, $SQL_User_ID, $SQL_Psychology_FirstName, $SQL_Psychology_LastName, $SQL_Result_Date, $SQL_Result_Time);
      }
      echo "<pre>";print_r($Res_Array);echo "</pre>";
}
```

**Problem:** It seems that it ignores my condition which is `if(in_array($SQL_Result_Time, $Res_Array, true)){break; }` and still inserts the value into the array. It still duplicates data

**Question:**

1. How to prevent the duplication data where if the current value was found inside the array it would just skip the statement and proceed to another value for checking the array and so on?
2. Is my logic on checking the value on the array is right?

Comment: Look carefully at the declaration of `$Res_Array`...

Comment: Please have a look at this.  The difference between break and a continue statement. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4364796/2295484

Comment: my bad... I just declared it outside the while loop because every loop it erases all values inside the array because of its declaration causing my problem. @Scott

Comment: Do you really want to put each item individually into the result array (using `array_push()`) or do you want them as one item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-initialising your array on every iteration of the `while loop`. You should declare it *outside* of the loop:

```
$Res_Array = array();
while ($Result_Data_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($Result)){ //130 rows from database
      $SQL_Result_Time = $Result_Data_2['Interpretation_Time'];

      /* Some statements here */

      if(in_array($SQL_Result_Time, $Res_Array, true)){
          break;
      }
      else{
          array_push($Res_Array, $Number, $SQL_Questionnaire_ID, $SQL_User_ID, $SQL_Psychology_FirstName, $SQL_Psychology_LastName, $SQL_Result_Date, $SQL_Result_Time);
      }
      echo "<pre>";print_r($Res_Array);echo "</pre>";
}
```

Also, as mentioned by Marvin Fischer in his answer, your `break` statement will terminate the `while loop` on the first duplicated value. You should instead use `continue`

```
while ($Result_Data_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($Result)){ //130 rows from database
      ...
      if(in_array($SQL_Result_Time, $Res_Array, true)){
          continue;
      }
      ....
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364757/difference-between-break-and-continue-in-php) should clarify any issues you have with `break` and `continue` statements

Answer (score 0):

First of all, inside of a loop you should use continue, otherwise you cancel the whole loop, secondly you empty `$Res_Array` at the beginning of every loop purging the old data, inserting the new one and echoing it again