# Why does this this PHP snippet output these specific values?

Tags: php, foreach

```
<?php 
    $numbers=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    $sum=0;
    foreach($numbers as $number)
     {
       if($sum>20){
        // break;
        continue;
     }
      $sum=$sum+$number;
     }
     echo $sum."".$number;
     ?>
```

I'm expecting `21 10`, but I don't know why. If I put `$sum>30` then I'm getting my desired answer but not the same with the above snippet. Please explain the answer in detail.

Comment: `I'm expecting 21 10`, that is what you get so what is question? Where are you changing to 30 and why are you doing that?

Comment: @vikas did you ask ChatGPT to explain why your code doesn't work?  It's usually worth a crack.  It will be easier to read and maintain your code if you use good code tabbing/formatting -- this way you can plainly see your condition blocks and loops.

Comment: Are you asking for the [Difference between break and continue in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4364757/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over an array of ten numbers, totalling them as you go. Once the sum is greater than 20 (which will be at $number = 6, $sum = 21) the condition executes a `continue` statement, which passes control to the end of the `for` loop, ready for the next iteration.

Your `continue` statement is causing your code to skip the line that updates the total, but the loop continues to iterate. Thus, when the loop terminates at the end of the array, `$number` is 10, the last element, and `$sum` is 21, the first total more than 20.